# Hive: Distribute Clause does not work well in aggregate query

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce

I'm using hive on MRv2. I was writing queries which contain aggregate functions. Then I thought that I want to manipulate assignments to the reducer. So I try to use DISTRIBUTE Clause.

For example, If I wrote query like `SELECT byear, sex, count(*) FROM customers GROUP BY byear, sex DISTRIBUTE BY byear, sex` and the number of byear value is 5(2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005) and that of sex value is 3(male, female, unknown), the number of reducer is `5 * 3 = 15` and retrieved data is assigned to each reducer which corresponding to byear value and sex value.

Or If I wrote query like `SELECT byear, sex, count(*) FROM customers GROUP BY byear, sex DISTRIBUTE BY byear`, then the number of the reducer is 5.

I expected this kind of behaviour. But in above queries, the number of the reducer is 1. Is it meaningless if the retrieved data is small enough? Or I mistook while writing the query?

The customers table contains 1,000,000 tuples and size is 30MB.

**addition**

1, I misunderstood the calculation method of the number of the reducer. I checked   `hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer` and calculated `file size / hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer` the number of the reducer is collect.
I thought that the DISTRIBUTE clause certifies data will be assigned each reducer based on attributes which are written in the clause, however the number of the reducer is not equal to that of the type of value.

2, I read EXPLAIN result to check the DISTRIBUTE clause effect, but there are no difference in the reault.